# Responsive design - not showing my tablet design on tablet

Tags: android, css, tablet

I have a responsive site built with some media queries: mobile, tablet, and desktop. When I view my site on my 7 inch samsung galaxy tab 2 vertically i get the mobile view, and when I view it horizontally it appears as my desktop view.

So my questions is, is this happening because of the device's display itself and where I set my break point? Or does it have something to do with the wrong meta? Or maybe something different altogether?

Meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Example of media query

```
@media all and (min-width: 670px)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Samsung Galaxy Tab 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_2_7.0#Features) has a resolution of 1024x600px. Therefore, styles set within the media query you've provided will not be applied when the tablet is in portrait mode, since the viewport width will only be 600px.